# Qt, MySQL and Ubuntu. Error: "driver not loaded"

Tags: mysql, linux, qt

The plugin was compiled and installed as here [qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html).

- `libqt5sql5-mysql` was installed
- `mysql-client` was installed

Code:

```
QPluginLoader loader("path-to-your-driver/libqsqlmysql.so");
loader.load();
qDebug() << loader.errorString();
```

shows

```
"Unknown error"
```

output from `qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();`

> "QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7"

I have

```
$ls -l /Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/
libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0
libqsqlite.so
libqsqlmysql.so
libqsqlpsql.so
```

and

```
$ldd libqsqlmysql.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff381bf000)
    libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0x00007f67e891a000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /home/maxim/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f67e86da000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/maxim/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f67e7f9d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f67e7c99000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f67e78d3000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f67e76b9000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f67e74b5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f67e7297000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f67e6f90000)
    libicui18n.so.53 => /home/maxim/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.53 (0x00007f67e6b44000)
    libicuuc.so.53 => /home/maxim/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.53 (0x00007f67e67b9000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f67e65b6000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f67e63ae000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f67e60a6000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f67e5e8f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f67e9086000)
    libicudata.so.53 => /home/maxim/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.53 (0x00007f67e4807000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f67e45c8000)
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Do you mean the `libqt5sql5-mysql` package when you write `libqt5-sql-mysql`? You don't need that since you must use the driver that matches your Qt version (5.4) from your home directory.

Comment: @SimonWarta Linux Mint 17 "Qiana" (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). 
Yes, the libqt5-sql-mysql was installed.

Comment: There is no such package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libqt5-sql-mysql&searchon=names If you got it from somewhere else or I am just to stupid to find it, please add a link. One other thing: is your quoted `ls` command wrong? I think you installed Qt in your home directory …

Comment: I'm so sorry! Of course the package is libqt5sql5-mysql.
Indeed, Qt installed in /home directory.
How do you think, the problem because of this?

Comment: No I don't think it has anything todo with the real problem. But if your input data (i.e. the question) is not correct, you should not expect anyone to understand it and help you. Please edit the question, such that every single character of the provided information is correct.